# Regular expression to compare the word starting with /abc/

Tags: java, regex

The requirement is, I have a text field which has to allow only texts starting with "/abc/"

For example : It has to allow **/abc/example_1234** . But it has to throw error for example/abc/1234.

I have tried `/^[\/app\/0-9A-Za-z-_|\/\ ]{1,18}\z/` . It has not worked out for my requirement.

kindly Suggest me.

Comment: `.startsWith()`?

Comment: Your attempted regex seems off from the inputs you describe.  Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this

```
^\/abc\/.*
```

It should allow all string starting with "/abc/" .